# 3 way handshake in TCP connection

Tags: tcp, ip, handshake

I have a question about the TCP's three way handshake - Why there are three messages before the connection start? Why does the server reply with another `seq_num` after the first message from the client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. So that the client knows the connection has been accepted, and
2. So that a sequence number for the direction server -> client had been established, as it's a full-duplex connection, i.e. with independence on each direction.